# Subclass Overwrite c++

Tags: c++, dynamic, subclass, overwrite

I'm trying to get my head around why I can't overwrite a subclass object with another subclass object if they share base class.

Say that **Letter** is the base class. **A** and **B** are subclasses. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
Letter* a_p = new A();
Letter* b_p = new B();

delete a_p;
*a_p = *b_p;
```

My ambition is to change what is located at a certain adress so that all pointers to the adress in question changes what they point to. In the above example, I'd like to somehow change the "content" of a_p to a copy of the "content" of b_p.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Why trying to complicate thing using boost. It's better to understand how memory / pointer, ... work before using boost...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing a copy of the object and the type of the pointer is the base class, you lose all information about the subclasses.

And since you delete a_p, doing `*a_p=` is wrong because `a_p` is pointing to a memory not anymore allocated.

Why not just doing : `a_p = b_p;` ?

Comment: My hopes where that I could "fill the empty space" left after I'd deleted a_p with a copy of b_p simply by using the operator=. Since they where of the same base class, I had hoped it was possible. I'm quite sure I was wrong.

Comment: After a delete there is no empty space ?! The application doesn't own anymore this section of memory.

Comment: @Gikkman: What happens if class A has 3 fields and class B has 20 fields?  In my understanding, there would be an overwriting of memory because the space allocated to class A is not big enough to hold all of class B.  This seems to be a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 2):

In the sample code you've given, the most prominent mistake is that you dereference a previously deleted pointer. But lets say those were objects on the stack;

```
class Base
{
};

class A : public Base
{
};

class B : public Base
{
  int a;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  b = a; // This gives an error
  return 0;
}
```

We are attempting to copy an `A` object into a `B` object, which has a different memory layout (an added int member). How would that member be initialized, do you reckon!? For the same reason, you are not allowed to have a pointer to `A` point to an object of `B`, they are different types.

The only place those two types are "the same" is where you access them through a `Base` pointer.

Comment: This was very helpful. I feel quite stupid, to be honest, that I didn't realize this myself.

Comment: @Gikkman, don't feel that way. Everybody who ever learned C++ had a similar d'oh!! moment at some point. :)

Answer (score 1):

A and B may not be the same size in memory.
Also, delete dealocates the memory allocated for a_p.
You would be writing to unallocated memory. That would cause 'undefined behaviour'

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to assign the pointer values, which I think you are, then you need to do

`a_p = b_p`

not `*a_p = *b_p`